# remote desktop client with panning of large desktops?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When using the standard Windows remote desktop client in Full Screen to connect to a large remote desktop, the result is usually that the remote desktop is resized to a smaller size matching the local display. Are there any RDP clients that in Full Screen instead leave the remote desktop at its original size and pan this larger area when the mouse reaches the border edges of the local display?

EDIT: As commented by Sam Cogan I should clarify that I am thinking about client OS:s and the console session, ie an existing login session whose desktop size matches the screen resolution on the remote computer. It is possible to connect to a remote console session without resizing its desktop size using the standard RDP client displayed as a normal window, but not in full-screen mode. Full-screen mode has a number of advantages, and f ex Linux does desktop panning in a very convenient way, so I'm hoping there is something similar for RDP. Also, this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338630(VS.85).aspx) suggests there may even be built-in support for it.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: What are you RDP'ing to? If you are RDP'ing to a client OS (vista, xp etc) then you are accessing the console session, so it will match that of the client. If you are accessing a server OS then you should be able to set what ever size you want.

Comment: Sorry about the missing information, I've edited the question!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the command line options to specify the size you want for the remote desktop?

```
mstsc.exe /w:Width/h:Height
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've tried both this and hand-editing desktopwidth/height in the .rdp connection file. It works fine for windowed mode but not for full-screen mode, and requires use of scrollbars for panning instead of just moving the mouse onto the display edge.

Answer (score 0):

In RDCM got to Edit > Properties > Display Settings click on Source: Default settings group

[image]

Select the above options and try again.